# For SQLAlchemy query, how to add filter 'not' clause?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I using flask-appbuilder with SQLAlchemy models, I find all their datamodel filter using "and" relationship.

I mean when the flask query something, it do:

```
self.datamodel.filter_by(id='abt').filter_by(testz_pro='mytest')
```

But I want to using 'or' relationship:

the sql like:

```
select * from number where id='1232' or id ='34343'
```

So, I have to change the 'or' relationship to 'and'

So, My sql is like:

```
select * from number where not (id<>'1232' and id<>'34343')
```

I just do not know for SQLAlchemy query how to expressure 'not'.

Can you give me example?

Comment: Does it have `IN` and `NOT IN` operators?

Comment: I see in some other questions that it has `.in_()` and `.notin_()`.

Comment: I think I can not do that since the .in_() or .notin_() only affect the immediate clause, I may have another conditional for example 'like', I want all the clauses with 'not' conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [filter](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html?highlight=filter#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.filter) method for this, as it is not possible to negate `filter_by`'s keyword arguments.

```py
from sqlalchemy import and_, not_

session.query(MyModel).filter(not_(and_(MyModel.id='abt', MyModel.testz_pro='mytest')))
```